# How to use early stopping for training deep neural network in TensorFlow 1.4?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

From some moment in the training process of a convolutional neural network, the cost function is not getting better. I want to define the condition to stop the training. I have found one solution using [ValidationMonitor](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.1/get_started/monitors) in TensorFlow 1.1. However, there is no way to do this in TensorFlow 1.4...

**My question**: How to use [early stopping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_stopping) in TensorFlow 1.4, especially with [Experiment](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/Experiment) and [Estimator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator)?

Please, checkout my [code](https://github.com/datbui/enhancer)

Answer (score 0):

Since `ValidationMonitor` doesn't work well with distributed training, We decided not to implement it as a Hook. We're waiting for a distributed friendly version of it.

As a workaround you can wrap `ValidationMonitor` as a hook. Following code shows how to do it:

`validation_hook = tf.contrib.learn.monitors.replace_monitors_with_hooks([validation_monitor], estimator)[0]`